# Call the same method but with different arguments, better way

Tags: ruby, hash, metaprogramming, ruby-hash

I have something like this in my function with calls the print_hash function three times but with different args. How to do it nicer?
The print_hash function is just only about print key and value.

```
print_hash(@hash1)
print_hash(@hash2)
print_hash(@hash3)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can change `print_hash`, change it to `print_hash(*hashes)`. Then you can simply say `print_hash @hash1, @hash2, @hash3`. `hashes` is an array you then iterate inside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
[@hash1, @hash2, @hash3].each(&method(:print_hash))
```